# How does comparing images through md5 work?

Tags: php, image, hash, compare, md5

Does this method compare the pixel values of the images? I'm guessing it won't work because they are different sizes from each other but what if they are identical, but in different formats? For example, I took a screenshot and saved as a `.jpg` and another and saved as a `.gif`.

Comment: A hash will let you compare 32-bit long hashes only, which is significally faster than comparing images itself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An MD5 hash is of the actual binary data, so different formats will have completely different binary data.

so for MD5 hashes to match, they must be **identical** files.  (There are exceptions in [fringe cases.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities))

This is actually one way forensic law enforcement finds data it deems as contraband. (in reference to images)

Comment: so If I have an image and compress it with jpeg for example, and do that 10 times on 10 different machines, will the compressed image always have the same md5? is jpeg compression deterministic?

Answer (score 11):

It is an MD5 Checksum - the same thing you often see when downloading a file, if the MD5 of the downloaded file matches the MD5 given by the provider, then the file transfer was successful.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum  If there is even 1 bit of difference between the 2 files then the resulting hash will be completely different.

Due to the difference in encoding between a JPG and GIF, the 2 will not have the same MD5 hash.

Comment: This explains MD5, but does not answer his actual question which is about if it can compare different image formats.

Comment: It is implied by the "If there is even 1 bit of difference between the 2 files then the resulting hash will be completely different."  I will change the answer though.

Answer (score 5):

`md5` is a hash algorithm, so it does not *compare images* but it compares *data*. The data you put in can be nearly anything, like the contents of a *file*. It then outputs a hashstring based on the *contents*, which is the raw data of the file.

So you basically do not compare *images* when feeding the image into `md5` but the *raw data* of the image. The hash algorithm does not know anything about it but the raw data, so a *jpg* and an *gif* (or any other image format) of the same screenshot will never be the same.

Even if you compare the *decoded image* it will not put out the same hash but will have small differences the human eye cannot see (depending on the amount of compression used). This might be different when comparing the **decoded data** of *lossless encoded images*, but I don't know here.

Take a look at the [wikipedia article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) for a more detailed explanation and technical background about hash functions.

Answer (score 3):

A .jpg file starts with 'JFIF', a .gif starts with 'GIF' when you look at the raw bytes. In otherwords, comparing the on-disk bytes of the "same image" in two different format is pretty much guaranteed to produce two different MD5 hashes, since the file's contents differ - even if the actual image is the "same picture".

To do a hash-based image comparison, you have to compare two images using the same format. It would be very very difficult to produce a .jpg and a .gif of the same image that would compare equal if you converted them to (say) a .bmp. It'd be the same fileformat, but the internal requirements of .gif (8bit, RLE/LZW lossless compression) v.s. the internal requirements of .jpg (24bit, lossy discrete cosine transform compression) mean it's nigh-on impossible to get the same .bmp from both source images.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comparing hashes then every single byte of the two images will have to match - they can't use different compression formats, or "look the same". They have to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

md5 is a hash. It is a code that is calculated from a bunch of data - any data really.

md5 is certainly not unique, but the chance that two different images have the exact same code is quite small. Therefor you could compare images by calculating an md5 code from each of them and compare the codes.

Comment: I'd like to add, that I wouldn't trust this method completely. Any duplicate images found should still be checked by their exact content.

Comment: That's unnecessary, paranoid even. See this for the math: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537989/is-using-2-different-hash-functions-a-good-way-to-check-for-file-integrity

Comment: Yeah, probably. But I learned you can never be sure. It's probably 3 lines of code to do a binary compare, and you only need to do that if the two md5s do indeed match and other simple checks (like file size, pixel size or meta information) match too. This will keep you from needing to hash every file. Only files with same sizes and meta info need to be hashed. I think that might give you a better optimization (especially when comparing larger images, like foto's) than just hashing every image you have and compare those hashes. But it depends on the situation of course.

Comment: I see now that it's not about files, but about screen shots. That will be of little use. Gif has a limited color depth and Jpeg suffers loss of quality due to the compression algorithm. It's improbably that a screenshot of a jpg and a screenshot of a gif will result in exactly the same image.

Comment: In that case it would be better to match pixel by pixel with a given tolerance. Pixels outside that tolerance could be counted as well. That will result in a certain 'distance' between two images. Images of the same size and with only a small distance are likely to display the same image.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare using the MD5 sum, as all the other posters have noted.  However, you can compare the images in a different way, and it will tell you their similarity regardless of image type, or even size.  You can use libPuzzle

http://libpuzzle.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle

This is a great library for image comparison and works very well.

Comment: Thanks for tip on libpuzzle, we use PHP, but seems the library is currently more for *nix systems, no Windows, so less effective for us. Also wanted to point out, for those that want a more complete solution to image compare that's both a library and an end user tool, check out Sikuli.org. The tool is also cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

It will still not work. Any image contains the header portion and the binary image buffer. In the said scenario
1. The the headers will be different between .jpg & .gif resulting in a different md5 sum
2. The image buffer itself may be different due to image compression as used by say the .jpg format.

Answer (score 0):

`md5sum` is a tool used to verify the integrity of files, as virtually any change to a file will cause its MD5 hash to change.

Most commonly, `md5sum` is used to verify that a file has not changed as a result of a faulty file transfer, a disk error or non-malicious meddling. The `md5sum` program is included in most `Unix-like` operating systems or compatibility layers such as `Cygwin`.

**Hence it cannot be used to compare images.**

Running `md5sum` on images will generate `md5 hash` based on images raw data. The output of hash strings for these images will not be the same since image format are not the same i.e. GIF and JPEG.

In addition, if you compare the sizes of these images will not be the same either. Usually `GIF` images can be bigger than `JPEG` files, which means `MD5 hash` strings will not tally at all.