# CSS cross-browser test with screenshots

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom, automated-tests

Currently I'm working with unit tests for JS project. The only thing i can do automated test for is functionality.

Question: is there any way to automate appearance testing? I mean that currently i wont know that some styles, that work perfectly in Chrome, are off in IE unless i will open IE browser and take a look at my page.

I was thinking about taking screenshots of the page during all DOM events with the same window size/resolution. Them compare those images and if there are any significant differences then spit it out as a failed test ("bug found" sorta thing).

Is there anything like that out there? I don't really want to re-invent the wheel.

**I'm NOT asking "how can i take a screenshot of the web-site" I'm asking "how i can analyze already taken screenshot"**

Comment: for IE there is www.iescreenshot.com/

Answer (score 1):

i dont know about automation .. but you can use a cross browser service to test your website in like:

http://www.browserstack.com/

also there is also Browsershots:

http://browsershots.org/

but the best way to test is to just open the website in the different browsers and view it  to get the most accurate rendering of functionality and display issues based on different browser versions

**UPDATE**

automated thumbnail screenshot service:

http://www.shrinktheweb.com

for IE there is

http://www.iescreenshot.com/

unless you do something on your server that captures screenshots of the different resolution

and or what @michaelt suggest below

**Other UPDATE**

I see your example below.. there is also this

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/

this type of image library just show difference in pixel data .. to make it automated you would have to mix js, ajax to talk to the server and capture and compare the images.. but it would require it to compare the number of colors in the image, and if those colors are the same in each image in conjunction with the luminosity.. and then having it run on a cron job on the server ...

another way of comparing pixel data in this stackoverflow question:

[How does comparing images through md5 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853185/how-does-comparing-images-through-md5-work)

i hope it helps

Comment: Not really. I was asking about automation. Not "open-and-look-yourself" thing. I know that there are a whole bunch of online tools for that

Comment: have you looked at this.. its automated thumbnail screenshot service .. http://www.shrinktheweb.com

Comment: also the browsershots.org link above is automated.. you put the browsers you want to test.. it gets put in the queue.. and then automatically grabs screenshots of all the browsers and then saves them on the server for you to review

Comment: Uh. one more time: i dont have a problem with screenshots, i have a problem with analyzing them.  "For you to view" - absolutely not what i need

Comment: sorry i understand.. but i just dont see how you can find something that will analyze screenshots in a automated way.. how would it know what pixels were good and what were pixels were bad? I couldn't see how it could tell the difference, even if comparing to know that difference if something was out up place, versus just using your best tool.. your eyes! ..unless im wrong and you have an example of this type of automated system .. thx

Comment: sort of like this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php (see first example)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying out [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). The WebDriver interface is really rich with functionality, taking screenshots for example, and there are so called drivers for a large number of different browsers including [Internet Explorer](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html). There are a few JavaScript implementations of WebDriver, and I've used [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) and [WebdriverJs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) with different amounts of success.

If you choose to go with a JavaScript implementation, you can relatively easily start using WebDriver as part of any unit test written in Mocha or what not.

**Edit:**

It seems as if I've misunderstood your question. If you want to compare screenshots, you could use an image recognition tool such as [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). I've only used it's Java API, but it's available for Python as well. Sikuli can easily be part of any test written in for example TestNG or JUnit. Give it an image, and it will search a given region (or the whole screen) for images that looks like it. If it finds a part of the screen that looks like the image, it will return it to you along with the level of how certain it is that they're the same.

For your use case, you could have a images on some file server representing how parts of your page *should* look, and have the test make sure that they all exist. If Sikuli can't find them, or finds them but with a very low degree of certainty, you'll fail the test.